# How could Nathan fly away even though the Haitian guy was next to him?

Tags: heroes

In Season One of *Heroes*, M. Bennett and The Haitian guy trap Nathan Petrelli (in the morning after he slept with Niki/Jessica), but he [Nathan] just flies away...

It is later revealed that the Haitian guy can neutralize powers. **Why wouldn't he do that to Nathan if they want to take him?**

Comment: Where are you in the series/do you care about spoilers?

Comment: I'm currently watching the season 3

Comment: real question is where the smoke comes from when he flies....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the season three episode (S3E12) [Our Father](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1054833/?ref_=ttep_ep12) we see that the Haitian must put forth effort to stop someone's powers.  In fact, he can barely hold on to

> Arthur

long enough for someone to kill him, and in the process is very clearly struggling to retain control.

I got the impression that Nathan simply took the Haitian and Noah by surprise, and the Haitian did not have time to stop Nathan before Nathan was out of range.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is ever answered in the series, I think we do know that the Haitian's abilities aren't automatic, he has to want to take away the person's powers.

> The Haitian knows that Nathan is Claire's real father, and he (the Haitian) has his own agenda concerning Claire (he later refuses to wipe her memories).  Also, he may have recognized Nathan as the son of Angela Petrelli, one of the founders of the secret organization and he let Nathan escape, believing Angela wouldn't want him exposed.

Answer (score -3):

As Geoff said, it is never answered in the series. However, if you note, Bennett comments something along the lines of "I didn't realize your powers had developed that much". I can think of the following possibilities based on this:

- Nathan might be having more control than the Haitian
- There might been a small gap in the Haitian's ability which Nathan was able to realize and instinctively fly off.